# Customizing cout from a class with options

Tags: c++, cout

I would like to have a function that acts like cout but with some options.

Eg : `MyFunc(0) << "Cats like to drink milk " << 2 << endl;`
when its 0, there shouldn't be any output

When its like this :

```
MyFunc(1) << "Cats like to drink milk " << 2 << endl;
```

I should see the output "Cats like to drink milk2". I read from several forums that ostream needs to be used, but I am not sure how I can use it for my purpose. MyFunc is a class basically, with 1, 0 options to the constructor.

I have seen things like this, but I don't get how it works.

```
Log& operator<< (std::ostream &(*f)(std::ostream &)){
cout << *f;
return *this; 
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved any of the simpler parts of this problem? Like writing a class that acts like `cout` without being particular about the number?

Comment: Well, you should generally shy away from inheriting from objects in standard namespace, but I could foresee you wrapping up `std::cout` and implementing the `<<` operator for all the [same types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4970cbea5b144ec7)

Comment: @AndyG, appreciated. What I was precisely looking for !

Comment: @user42826: I should mention that the implementation I provided is pretty inefficient because every time you log a message you are allocating and deallocating memory. You could get around this trickery with static data members, or simply use a templated logger, with the template differentiating which stream to use.

Answer (score 0):

It basically goes like this:

```
class CoutPlus {
public:
    CoutPlus(int& i) : m_bOn(i) {}
    template<class T> CoutPlus& operator<<(const T& val) {
        if (m_bOn)
            std::cout << val;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    bool m_bOn;
};
```

You decide what to do with empty constructor and assignment, and whether to implement other ostream's member functions.